# How to stop strangers sending me event invites in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events, facebook-privacy

I relocated and some requests are too country-specific. I am looking for a way to block all requests to other countries. I can only block events from my friends but not from non-friends, strangers and friends of friends. How can I block events from strangers?